# ControlsFx BreadCrumbBar setOnAction event listener issue

Tags: javafx-8, controlsfx

I am trying to add a BreadCrumbbar to my JavaFx application using ControlsFx library.
It is getting added but i am not able to add listener to listen for any click action on my breadcrumbbar.
I have tried setonCrumbAction() function but not able to exactly implement that.

Any sample for same would be really helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
breadCrumBar.setOnCrumbAction(new EventHandler<BreadCrumbBar.BreadCrumbActionEvent<TreeItem<?>>>()              
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(BreadCrumbActionEvent<TreeItem<?>> event) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });
```

Hopefully it will resolve your issue